# Return to the Magento default theme in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, default

I want to return to the default theme of Magento, but when i put "default" in the "Current Package Name" space there are no changes on my website.

The site is the same as before.

I want to do this because I want to understand if one error on my site was caused from the theme or from the code.

[image]

Comment: have you clear cache?

Comment: Yes, I had clear the cache

Comment: Check your Configuration Scope when making that change to ensure that you don't have anything different in Vista Negozio/Store View.

Comment: I have "default" in all my Store View

Comment: Try changing "default" to "base"?

Comment: Is the same thing, no change

Comment: Use Following steps :

System >> Design >> Add Design Change >> select your custom design from dropdown.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes, It works! Tahnk you!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've added it to the wrong place, I can't confirm as it isn't in English.

It should look like the below screenshot, also make sure you have the store scope set to incase it's defined at a store level rather than the default config scope.

Also clear your caches.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1- In the Admin panel, go to System > Configuration > Design.

2- In the Store View drop-down field, select the store view where you want to apply the theme.

3- On the Design interface column enter (default) //Generaly the first input

4- Make sure all inputs under the “Themes” section are empty, then Click Save Config.

5- If caching is enabled, clear the cache.

6- To see your changes applied, reload the store front pages.